# Comment box only half a line tall on mobile

Tags: bug, comments, design, mobile-web

When viewing on mobile, the comment line is only half a line tall, making it really hard to read what I'm typing and fix whatever autocorrect is butchering. Can we make it taller?

It was tested in Chrome and Firefox on my Galaxy S8. It renders correctly when I tell the browser to "Request Desktop", but I think it should also work in mobile view:

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Your HTML table tags are ignored here (`<table>`, `<td>`, etc.).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen weird, they render as a table on my screen